# New Mac - new SSH keys for github?

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion

I was happily using git on my old Mac (Leopard), then migrated to a new (Lion) Mac. I installed Github for Mac, and I can clone repositories using that - but not from Terminal.

Any git clone from Terminal gets:

fatal: https://github.com/user/repository.git/info/refs download error - The requested URL returned error: 403

Any git pull from Terminal gets:

fatal: https://github.com/user/repository.git/info/refs download error - The requested URL returned error: 401

Do I need to start again and generate new keys? I assumed everything would be migrated with my user account (the contents of ~/.ssh are unchanged).

Comment: It turns out that I have git version 1.6.3.1 and I need 1.7.7 to resolve my http issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `https` url and ssh keys don't even matter. Make sure you have your `user.name` and `email` for git configured properly in your new Mac ( and while you are at it, config `github.user` and `github.token` as well)

Comment: Thanks - these are OK, and git is present, but I need a newer version.