# Using SSH Keys on different Mac

Tags: macos, git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have GIT and my repos setup on a MacBook Air. I'm trying to clone the repo on my iMac. My understanding was that I needed to copy my key over from the /.ssh folder on the MBA to the same folder iMac.

However, when I try and clone the repo on the iMac, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've done a little research already and have verified that...

- I have the latest version of GIT and that my user.name and user.email variables are configured correctly. ([New Mac - new SSH keys for github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029182/new-mac-new-ssh-keys-for-github))
- the ownership & permissions on the .gitconfig file and parent folder are r/w and owned by my user. ([Trouble setting up Tower with my GitHub Account - error: could not lock config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340581/trouble-setting-up-tower-with-my-github-account-error-could-not-lock-config-f))
- my $HOME environment variable points to my users working directory. ([Trouble setting up git with my GitHub Account error: could not lock config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959972/trouble-setting-up-git-with-my-github-account-error-could-not-lock-config-file))

At this point, I am all out of ideas and could really use some advice.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Which files did you copy? `id_rsa` *and* `id_rsa.pub`? Also, are you sure you have the URI right?

Comment: Yes on the file names and the URI. As I mentioned in my own response below, my issue was solved by letting SSH know the keys existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I found the solution right after I got done posting this, but for those who are copying keys to new machines, you have to let SSH know the keys are there. See this answer for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12100237/337824